# How to add ethereum node to already existing blockchain without knowing genesis file?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

i am new blockchain
Target : i want to add new node to already running blockchain.

Correct, if i am wrong for adding node to network. two node's should have same genesis block.
if genesis block have different values then newly setup node will not be able to mine the transaction from already running blockchain.

Issue :
i dont have gensis.json for creating same gensis block on new node.

Tried :
i have tried to setup gensis block but live blockchain gensis block value is different from newly setup on local system.
Checked by connecting to geth console and running following command in console.

```
admin.nodeInfo
```

so when i add peers using following command it returns true.

```
admin.addPeer("endoevaluefromec2instance")
```

when i list peers on ec2 instance it shows count 0.

```
0
```

Note : i am able to connect to blockchain using web3 module so i don't think there is connectivity issue
Question :

1. How can i create gensis.json file from already running etherum instance ?
2. Is there any other way to add node to already running instance or mine the transaction ?
3. How can i take backup of already running blockchain and restore on system ?

Comment: Do you have access to other nodes as in the the file directories?

Comment: @Ming thanks for responding actually i have to create node and add it to the network so that i would have multiple node running . i have access of already running etherum node.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to existing node and assume they are runing similar client, you can actually copy the `chaindata` folder over to the new node and then specify the `datadir` of the new node.

Ex:

If your geth datadir folder is at `/root/.ethereum`, copy over the entire `chaindata` from existing node to new node.
If your new node has no `geth` file directory, you can copy the `../geth` directory instead of `../geth/chaindata`.

Then run `geth` client with `--datadir` argument like this

```
$ geth --datadir /root/.ethereum/
```

Then you can `admin.addPeer` and should be syncing properly.